# Cluster extraction in different files for different regions

Tags: ros, pcd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am new in using Kinect.. I am trying to do a simple code for color recognition. I followed the tutorials in PCL library.  It worked for me and I identified the different clusters that I want to have. Now I have problem in extracting the data from these clusters.. I save each cluster in a PCD file. I got a problem where the second cluster is the equal to the firat cluster and the second cluster. The third cluster is equal to the first + second + third clusters. The forth cluster is equal to the First + second + third + forth cluster and so on. I identified this problem by running "rosrun pcl_ros pcltopointcloud" and visuliza the pcd files in RVIZ. Now I want each cluster alone without the others.

I have the following code and I don not know where I am mistaken.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/point_cloud_conversion.h>
#include <visualization_msgs/Marker.h>
#include <tf/transform_listener.h>
#include <tf/transform_broadcaster.h>
#include <tf/transform_datatypes.h>
#include <vector>
#include <pcl/search/search.h>
#include <pcl/segmentation/region_growing_rgb.h>
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>  
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h>
#include <pcl/filters/passthrough.h>
#include <pcl/filters/extract_indices.h>
#include <pcl/features/normal_3d.h>
#include <pcl/filters/project_inliers.h>
#include <pcl/surface/convex_hull.h>
#include <pcl/search/kdtree.h>
#include <pcl/segmentation/extract_polygonal_prism_data.h>
#include <pcl/segmentation/extract_clusters.h>
#include <pcl_ros/transforms.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h>
#include <pcl/ModelCoefficients.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/sample_consensus/method_types.h>
#include <pcl/sample_consensus/model_types.h>
#include <pcl/segmentation/sac_segmentation.h>


int main (int argc, char** argv) 
 {
    ros::init (argc, argv, "color_segmentation");
    ros::NodeHandle nh_;
    tf::TransformListener listener_;
    typedef pcl::PointXYZRGB Point;
    std::string processing_frame_="/camera_link";
    pcl::search::Search <pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr tree = boost::shared_ptr<pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZRGB> > (new   pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
    
  std::string topic = nh_.resolveName("/camera/depth_registered/points");
  ROS_INFO(" waiting for a point_cloud2 on topic %s", topic.c_str());
  sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::ConstPtr recent_cloud = ros::topic::waitForMessage<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>(topic);
  sensor_msgs::PointCloud old_cloud;
  sensor_msgs::convertPointCloud2ToPointCloud (*recent_cloud, old_cloud);

  sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 converted_cloud;
  sensor_msgs::convertPointCloudToPointCloud2 (old_cloud, converted_cloud);
  pcl::PointCloud<Point>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<Point>);
 // pcl::PointCloud <pcl::Point>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud <pcl::Point>);
   try
     {
     pcl::fromROSMsg(converted_cloud, *cloud);
     }
    catch (...)
    {
      ROS_ERROR("Failure while converting the ROS Message to PCL point cloud.  segmentation now requires the input cloud to have color info, so you must input a cloud with XYZRGB points, not just XYZ.");
     throw;
  }
  pcl::IndicesPtr indices (new std::vector <int>);
  pcl::PassThrough<pcl::PointXYZRGB> pass;
  pass.setInputCloud (cloud);
  pass.setFilterFieldName ("z");
  pass.setFilterLimits (0.0, 2.0);
  pass.filter (*indices);

  pcl::RegionGrowingRGB<pcl::PointXYZRGB> reg;
  reg.setInputCloud (cloud);
  reg.setIndices (indices);
  reg.setSearchMethod (tree);
  reg.setDistanceThreshold (10);
  reg.setPointColorThreshold (6);
  reg.setRegionColorThreshold (5);
  reg.setMinClusterSize (1000);
  std::vector <pcl::PointIndices> clusters;
  reg.extract (clusters);

  ROS_INFO ("Number of clusters found matching the given constraints: %d.", (int)clusters.size ());

  pcl::PointCloud <pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr colored_cloud = reg.getColoredCloud ();
  pcl::visualization::CloudViewer viewer ("Cluster viewer");
  viewer.showCloud (colored_cloud);
  pcl::io::savePCDFileASCII ("test_pcd.pcd", *colored_cloud);

  while (!viewer.wasStopped ())
     {
         boost::this_thread::sleep (boost::posix_time::microseconds (100));
     }
 
 // Cluster extraction 
  int j = 0;
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud_cluster (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
  for (std::vector<pcl::PointIndices>::const_iterator it = clusters.begin (); it != clusters.end (); ++it)
    {
        for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator pit = it->indices.begin (); pit != it->indices.end (); pit++)
        cloud_cluster->points.push_back (cloud->points[*pit]); //*
        cloud_cluster->width = cloud_cluster->points.size ();
        cloud_cluster->height = 1;
        cloud_cluster->is_dense = true;
        std::ostringstream ss;
        ss << j;
        pcl::PCDWriter writer5;
       writer5.write<pcl::PointXYZRGB> ("~/catkin_ws/cloud_objects"+ss.str()+".pcd", *cloud_cluster, false);
       std::cout << "PointCloud representing the Cluster: " << cloud_cluster->points.size () << " data points." << std::endl;
       j++;
   }
 return (0); 
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221658/cluster-extraction-in-different-files-for-different-regions/) by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2015-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In this part:

```
int j = 0;
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud_cluster (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
for (std::vector<pcl::PointIndices>::const_iterator it = clusters.begin (); it != clusters.end (); ++it)
  {
      for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator pit = it->indices.begin (); pit != it->indices.end (); pit++)
      cloud_cluster->points.push_back (cloud->points[*pit]); //*
      cloud_cluster->width = cloud_cluster->points.size ();
      cloud_cluster->height = 1;
      cloud_cluster->is_dense = true;
      std::ostringstream ss;
      ss << j;
      pcl::PCDWriter writer5;
     writer5.write<pcl::PointXYZRGB> ("~/catkin_ws/cloud_objects"+ss.str()+".pcd", *cloud_cluster, false);
     std::cout << "PointCloud representing the Cluster: " << cloud_cluster->points.size () << " data points." << std::endl;
     j++;
 }
```

you are adding each new cluster to previous one(s) and saving again. Therefore the result will be exactly as you explained.

You should clear point cloud at each iteration and fill it with only points of new cluster.

Try adding `cloud_cluster->clear();` for each cluster iteration, like;

```
int j = 0;
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud_cluster (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
for (std::vector<pcl::PointIndices>::const_iterator it = clusters.begin (); it != clusters.end (); ++it)
  {
      cloud_cluster->clear();
      for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator pit = it->indices.begin (); pit != it->indices.end (); pit++)
      cloud_cluster->points.push_back (cloud->points[*pit]); //*
      cloud_cluster->width = cloud_cluster->points.size ();
      cloud_cluster->height = 1;
      cloud_cluster->is_dense = true;
      std::ostringstream ss;
      ss << j;
      pcl::PCDWriter writer5;
     writer5.write<pcl::PointXYZRGB> ("~/catkin_ws/cloud_objects"+ss.str()+".pcd", *cloud_cluster, false);
     std::cout << "PointCloud representing the Cluster: " << cloud_cluster->points.size () << " data points." << std::endl;
     j++;
 }
```

**UPDATE:**
Also you can check [this](http://www.pcl-users.org/Save-segmented-objects-using-Region-Growing-td4029578.html).

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on 2015-11-29**:
You are right. I used cloud_cluster->clear(); and I extracted each cluster alone. Thank you.

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2015-11-29**:
You're welcome!